# Как создать функционирующий face id на python?

Tags: python

Как таковых толковых гайдов практически нет. Максимум что есть в наших и зарубежных ресурсах это определение самого лица, но этого не достаточно. Есть ли способы создать полностью функционирующий face id как на телефонах(например).Желателньо что бы это в дальнейшем можно было завязать как то на системах видео наблюдения. Вопрос задавал и ранее но ответа толкового не получил.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте по порядку.

1.*"Как таковых толковых гайдов практически нет"*. -  очень смелое заявление, сразу демонстрирующий уровень самостоятельной работы с информацией спрашивающего.

2. *Есть ли способы создать полностью функционирующий face id как на телефонах(например)*  -  нет конечно, создать "как на телефоне" на компьютере невозможно!  Интересно, вы мне поверили? Да? Нет? Почему?
3. *Желателньо что бы это в дальнейшем можно было завязать как то на системах видео наблюдения.*  -  не знаю, может быть и желательно.
4. *Вопрос задавал и ранее но ответа толкового не получил.* -  а можно ссылочку на "бестолковые ответы"?  Потому что в старом вопросе вам показали одну из 10000 ссылок на источник по вашей теме. На готовую библиотеку для решения вашей задачи.  Чем он оказался бестолковым?   Вы даже не сочли необходимым поблагодарить или хоть как-то отреагировать ответившему. От "того" вопроса прошло уже почти пять месяцев. И что вы так и не продвинулись в поисках ответа на эту тему? Одно могу сказать точно, что бы получить "толковый" ответ, надо 1) задать толковый вопрос 2) быть готовым понимать толковый ответ.